# How to get values of array elements?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm wondering if there is a way to generalize a function that formats data collected with `Get-WinEvent`. The full code appears below the function I'd like to modify.

Function A:

```
function Get-DataString() {
    param ([object]$Data, [int]$N)
    $string = ""
    foreach ($element in $Data) {
        if ($N -eq 2) {
            $string += '("' + $element.Id +'",' + '"' + $element.TimeCreated  + '"),'
        } else {
            $string += '("' + $element.TimeCreated  + '"),'
        }
    }
    $string = $string -replace “.$”
    $string
}
```

The results of this function look like this:
`("1","2024-02-14 15:40:12"),("1","2024-02-14 15:40:10"),...` and `("2024-02-14 07:56:21"),("2024-02-14 07:55:24"),...`

I'd like to generalize so that it's not necessary to have a parameter that tells how many values go inside the parentheses. But when I tried this:

Function B:

```
function Get-DataString() {
    param ([object]$Data)
    $string = ""
    foreach ($element in $Data) {
        foreach ($item in $element) {
            $string += '("' + $item  + '"),'
        }
        $string = $string -replace “.$”
    }
    $string = $string -replace “.$”
    $string
}
```

I get this:
`("@{Id=1; TimeCreated=2024-02-14 15:40:12}")("@{Id=1; TimeCreated=2024-02-14 15:40:10}")...` and `("@{TimeCreated=2024-02-14 07:56:21}")("@{TimeCreated=2024-02-14 07:55:24}")...`

Function C:

```
function Get-DataString() {
    param ([object]$Data, [array]$Fields)
    $string = ""
    foreach ($element in $Data) {
        $string += '('
        foreach ($word in $Fields) {
            $item = '"' + $element.$word + '"'
            $string += $item + ','
        }
        $string -replace “.$”
        $string += '"),'
    }
    $string = $string -replace “.$”
    return $string
}
```

yields: `'("2024-02-15 07:21:30","),...` where, e.g., `-Fields "Id","TimeCreated"`

The question, I guess, is what syntax, if any, will create the results of Function A without including a parameter that tells how many elements are involved.

Complete code (so far):

```
Add-Type –Path ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\Connector NET 8.0\MySql.Data.dll'
$Connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]@{ConnectionString='server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=aardvark;database=errors'}
$Connection.Open()
$MYSQLCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$MYSQLDataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter
$MYSQLDataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

$MYSQLCommand.Connection=$Connection
$MYSQLCommand.CommandText="SELECT MAX(session_off) 'Off' FROM sessions;"
$MYSQLDataAdapter.SelectCommand=$MYSQLCommand

# $NumberOfDataSets=$MYSQLDataAdapter.Fill($MYSQLDataSet, "data")
$MYSQLDataAdapter.Fill($MYSQLDataSet)

$after = $MYSQLDataSet.Tables[0].Off
$after

function Add-Events()
{
    param ([string]$Table, [string]$Fields, [string]$Values)
    $query = "INSERT INTO " + $Table + "("  + $Fields + ") VALUES " + $Values + ";"
    # $query
    $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand $query, $Connection
    $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

function Get-DataString() {
    param ([object]$Data, [int]$N)
    $string = ""
    foreach ($element in $Data) {
        if ($N -eq 2) {
            $string += '("' + $element.Id +'",' + '"' + $element.TimeCreated  + '"),'
        } else {
            $string += '("' + $element.TimeCreated  + '"),'
        }
    }
    $string = $string -replace “.$”
    $string
}

'power','errors' | 
ForEach-Object {
    switch ($PSItem) 
    { 
        power 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            # remote computer name is required
            Try {
                $power = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName 'GeoLaptop' -FilterHashtable @{
                    LogName     = 'System'
                    Id          = 1, 42
                    StartTime   = $after
                } | 
                # restrict properties to only those required 
                Select-Object -Property Id, @{label='TimeCreated';expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}}

                $vals = Get-DataString -Data $power -N 2
                Add-Events -Table 'power' -Fields "EventId, TimeCreated" -Values $vals
            } 
            Catch {
                $_.Message
            }
        } 
        errors 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            # remote computer name is required
            $errors = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName 'GeoLaptop' -FilterHashtable @{
                LogName     = 'System'
                Id          = 17
                StartTime   = $after
            } | 
            # restrict properties to only those required 
            Select-Object -Property @{label='TimeCreated';expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}} 
            $vals = Get-DataString -Data $errors -N 1
            Add-Events -Table 'errors' -Fields "TimeCreated" -Values $vals
    } 
        default {Write-Warning -Message 'No records which meet the criteria provided.'}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial code remains the same; code beginning with `function Add-Events()` has changed. The key to generalizing `function Get-DataString()` was passing to it an array of fields.

```
function Add-Events()
{
    param ([string]$Table, [string]$FieldNames, [string]$Values)
    $query = "INSERT INTO " + $Table + "("  + $FieldNames + ") VALUES " + $Values + ";"
    # $query
    $Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand $query, $Connection
    $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}

function Get-DataString() {
    param ([object]$Data, [array]$Fields)
    $string = ""
    foreach ($element in $Data) {
        $string += '('
        foreach ($word in $Fields) {
            $string += "'" + $element.$word + "',"
        }
        $string = $string -replace “.$”
        $string += "),"
    }
    $string = $string -replace “.$”
    return $string
}
'power','errors' | 
ForEach-Object {
    switch ($PSItem) 
    { 
        power 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            # remote computer name is required
            Try {
                $power = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName 'GeoLaptop' -FilterHashtable @{
                    LogName     = 'System'
                    Id          = 1, 42
                    StartTime   = $after
                } | 
                # restrict properties to only those required 
                Select-Object -Property Id, @{label='TimeCreated';expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}}

                $vals = Get-DataString -Data $power -Fields @("Id","TimeCreated")
                Add-Events -Table 'power' -FieldNames "EventId, TimeCreated" -Values $vals
            } 
            Catch {
                $_.Message
            }
        } 
        errors 
        {
            "Getting $PSItem data"
            # remote computer name is required
            $errors = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName 'GeoLaptop' -FilterHashtable @{
                LogName     = 'System'
                Id          = 17
                StartTime   = $after
            } | 
            # restrict properties to only those required 
            Select-Object -Property @{label='TimeCreated';expression={$_.TimeCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")}} 

            $vals = Get-DataString -Data $errors -Fields @("TimeCreated")
            Add-Events -Table 'errors' -FieldNames "TimeCreated" -Values $vals
    } 
        default {Write-Warning -Message 'No records which meet the criteria provided.'}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a hash table

```
function Get-DataString() {
    param ([object]$Data)
    $table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    foreach ($element in $Data) {
        $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{}
        foreach ($item in $element) {
            $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $item.Name -NotePropertyValue $item.Value
        }
        $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
    }
    $string = $string -replace “.$”
    return $table
}
```

Comment: I regret I am unable to comment adequately on this answer. After replacing the original `function Get-DataString()` with the above, the error `Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NotePropertyName'...` is thrown. It is not sufficiently obvious to me on how best to modify the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the method.  Why not : $errors | Export-CSV -Path filename

Comment: Interesting that you suggest CSV. That's where I started from, but thought it would be quicker to go directly to the database. Once I had a CSV I used a PHP script to load the database. Since this is just a hobby and a learning exercise, I'm seeking elegance in coding. The code I've got so far loads several hundred rows of data in less than a second. I'm surprised by how complex the `$Data` object turns out to be.